# PHP includes working into dev, but not into prod

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine into a PHP project I'm developing.

The folder structure is something like this below:

```
app
    -actions
    -controllers
    -doctrine
    -entities
    ConnectionFactory.class.php

css 
img
js
views
```

Ok, I'm trying to reference `Doctrine` inside the `ConnectionFactory` class.

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
require_once "Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php";

class ConnectionFactory {
    private static $instance;
    private $entityManager;

    private function __construct() { }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new ConnectionFactory();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function getEntityManager() {

        if($this->entityManager == null) {
            Setup::registerAutoloadPEAR();

            $debug = true;
            $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."/entities"), $debug);

            $conn = array(
                'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
                'user' => 'root',
                //'password' => 'root',
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'port' => 3306,
                'charset' => 'utf8',
                'dbname' => 'anuncios'
            );

            $this->entityManager = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
        }
        return $this->entityManager;
    }
}
?>
```

Well, it works like a charm in dev enviroment. When I push it to prod, I got an error:

```
require_once(Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php): failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in <b>/home/nifes651/public_html/www.mysite.com.br/main/app/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php</b> on line <b>74</b><br />
```

And I can't figure it out why this isn't working in prod. In dev works properly.

Anyone can help me? Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you clear the cache for prod by `php app/console cache:clear --env="prod" --no-debug`?

Comment: How can I do this? And where?

Comment: If you have Windows machine, open command prompt; redirect to the path of Symfony; then type the command on my previous comment. For more info http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/usage.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll try here and let you know!